# How to make GtkListView items flow from top to bottom, like in Thunar or Nautilus Compact View Mode?

Tags: python, listview, gtk, pygtk, gtk2hs

I'm now practicing with Gtk by developing a file manager application similar to Thunar, and I simply can't figure out how to make the IconView items flow vertically instead of horizontally, like in Thunar or Nautilus' Compact View mode, as well as in Windows Explorer's List View Mode. Should I use TreeView istead?

I'm practicing in Haskell bindings, the Gtk2Hs, but I'm also familiar with native C library and Python bindings (PyGtk), so explanations using these languages are also acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately, [Xfce's code](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tree/thunar/thunar-compact-view.c) is pretty abstract. Hopefully you can make some sense of it.

Comment: Did you forget to use a scrolled window?

Comment: No, surely I did wrap the IconView in a ScrolledWindow.

Comment: What happens if you set the horizontal scroll policy on the scrolled window to NEVER?

Comment: It still flows left-to-right. The same for vertical scroll policy, when it also streches the window vertically to the height of several screens regardless of orientation (which actually means whether the texts are located below or right to the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally seems that IconView has not such a feature right now, as Thunar uses its own control from `libexo`, while Caja/Nautilus use their own controls from other libraries.